# Cannot start windows xp in safe mode (dual boot system)

Tags: windows-7

I cannot start windows xp in safe mode, only windows 7 can start in safe mode. What can I do? when I press f8, only the safe mode options for windows 7 will show.

Comment: Did you try to press F8 right after you select to boot WinXP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your winxp and windows 7 use the same CPU Architecture? 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64)
I think having different architectures mesess with the boot up

Comment: they are both 32 bit.